# Create and call variables in python

Tags: python

I am new in python and have a simple question…
In my project there is an "student" class, and there are some student object (for example 100):

```
class students:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Some of these students are special (for example five), now I want to define three variables `z0, z1, z2` for each of these five special students:

```
for c in self.candidate_student:
   z0 
   z1 
   z2
```

After this part, I want to call each candidate student variable by name, like this:

```
student.name.z0
student.name.z1
student.name.z2
```

Can anyone explain how I can achieve this?

Comment: make `name` a class as well.

Comment: This appears to be a stereotypical application of subclass, using inheritance.  Was that not in your learning materials?

Comment: What is this `candidate_student` attribute of `students`?  How do you recognize which students are "special"?  Do they still have all of the attributes of a typical student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to define z0,z1 and z2 values for each of the 'special' students, you can set them as attributes of the object instances. Note you can add a new attribute to an object at any time, it doesn't have to be in the `__init__()` method. For example, if you are creating a new 'special student' object:

```
s = student("John Doe")
s.z0 = 7
s.z1 = 8
s.z2 = 9
```

Now, `s` just got three new attributes (besides `name`, which you set in `__init__`), you can address them like variables anywhere after they have been set. E.g., after the above:

```
print (s.name) # will print "John Doe"
print (s.z2) # will print 9
```

Note if you have code that works with both 'special' and 'non-special' objects, you should expect that the special attributes aren't always there (so if you try to use `student.z0` on an object that didn't have that set beforehand, you will get an exception).

Comment: Tnx so much! understand now! I thought like C base languages need to define all variables first, and I had problem with these special cases! but your answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to add properties to your special students this code might help:

```
class students:
    def __init__(self, name, z=None):
        self.name = name
        self.z = z or []
```

You can initialize your special student like this:

```
ana = students('Ana', ['Apple', 'Ball', 'Pen'])
```

And call the properties like this:

```
ana.z[0]
ana.z[1]
```

Comment: I think it dosen't work for me. Assume 'Ana' is an student object and I want to read something like this : (Ana.z0 + Ana.Z1)

Comment: @sali, how about now?

Comment: It isn't wrong. but I wanted to create (z0 to z2) variables jussst for special cases! I think, I found my answer now with other comments. tax for your time :)